# JTable only showing after I resize the JPanel in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable, jpanel

I have a button called `btnDisplay` on a `JPanel` called `TempPanel`.  When the button is clicked, it should display a `JTable` that is created manually.

However the table is only visible to me after I resize the panel manually with a mouse. Even if I make the panel smaller than it originally was, it shows the table, otherwise it doesn't.

What is the reason for this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container to which the `JTable` is been added

Comment: this worked, thank you man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing the comment as an answer for clarity purpose:

Call revalidate and repaint on the container to which the JTable is been added